# How to change the "error" prop of a material-ui element?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to validate a form field and have the following code:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {TextField} from '@material-ui/core';

class ProductField extends Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.isValid = this.isValid.bind(this);
    }

    isValid() {
        console.log("Checking if valid...");
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        console.log("this isn't working");
    }
    render() {

        return (

                <TextField style={{width:"100%"}} id={this.props.label} label={this.props.label} variant="outlined"
            hintText={this.props.label}
            helperText={this.props.meta.touched && this.props.meta.error}
            onChange={event => {
                console.log("changed");
                const { value } = event.target;
                this.setState({ searchValue: value });
            }}
            {...this.props.input}
                />
        );
    }

}

export default ProductField;
```

When onChange is called, I want to check the state of the TextField, and if this.props.meta.error is not empty I want to set the Text Field prop "error" and if it is empty then I want to unset the "error" prop. 
Right now, even the console.log("Checking if valid...") isn't working, suggesting that the onChange event isn't being fired at all. 
What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are updating state with the onChange, but my guess (I can't say for sure) is that the value and error data is coming from props. So the first issue is that it seems you aren't correctly controlling your input

Comment: *Right now, even the console.log("this isn't working") isn't working, suggesting that the onChange event isn't being fired at all.* This doesn't make sense. Why does the componentDidMount console log suggest something about the onChange?

Answer (score 0):

You have several issues in your code:

1. You need to initialize your `state` in the `constructor`, so the state will be reliable with you `Textfield`, also you have to set a property in the `state` that will handle if the `field` is `valid` or is an `error'.
2. You need to create a `method` to validate your `TextField` value, and inside this method update the `state` based on the validity of field, here you can add the `this.props.meta.error` or anything else that is validating your values, and remember to call the method that will validate your value after the `state` has been properly changed, maybe using it as a `callback` on the `setState`method .
3. You have to add a `prop` to your `TextField` component to catch if it is an `error` or if it is `valid`.

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { TextField } from "@material-ui/core";

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      searchValue: "",
      isValid: false
    };
    this.isValid = this.isValid.bind(this);
  }

  isValid() {
    console.log("Checking if valid...");
    this.setState({ isValid: this.state.searchValue.length > 6 });
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    console.log("this isn't working");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <TextField
        style={{ width: "100%" }}
        id={this.props.label}
        label={"example"}
        variant="outlined"
        error={!this.state.isValid && this.state.searchValue != ""}
        onChange={event => {
          console.log("changed");
          const { value } = event.target;
          this.setState({ searchValue: value }, () => {
            this.isValid();
          });
        }}
      />
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Check this [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sad-johnson-hy8id) for a working example

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using state to control your element's error prop.

For example, if you want to change the error prop of a TextField:

```
const [isInputValid, setIsInputValid] = useState(true);

// ...

<TextField id="vol-input" label="Volatility input"
           defaultValue="65 %" error={!isInputValid}/>
```

You can then change the `TextField` error state to `true` in your code as follows:

```
setIsInputValid(false);
```